# Superfish menu - how to remove parent sign: "PARENT_LINK >>"?

Tags: routes, theming, navigation

I built my main menu (horizontal) using superfish module.

All the parent links in the menu (that has drop down menu with childs) has a sign. 
For example it looks like that: "PARENT_LINK >>"

I really tried to find a solution through CSS files, but couldn't solve it.

How can I remove the ">>" sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your superfish block settings there should be a setting that reads "AUTO-ARROWS:" with a dropdown.

Set that to no (and save) and you shouldn't have any arrows anymore.